# how to avoid "Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode" with createWriteStream

Tags: node.js, lint

I have the following code

```
fs.createWriteStream( fileName, {
  flags: 'a',
  encoding: 'utf8',
  mode: 0644
});
```

I get a lint error

```
Octal literals are not allowed in strict mode.
```

What is the correct way to do this code so I won't get a lint error?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I don't have a node installation at hand, but looking at [sources](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/c7f424e44b7e61b89f91cd344599c3d1cdfb88fe/lib/fs.js#L419) it seems that they allow strings as well:

```
  mode     : '0644'
```

Does it work?

Comment: +1 That does look like a valid solution, given the source (assuming they're the right sources and version and so on).

Answer (score 73):

I came through this problem while using it in a scape squence:

```
console.log('\033c'); // Clear screen
```

All i had to do was convert it to Hex

```
console.log('\x1Bc'); // Clear screen
```

Comment: Exactly my problem! This solutions workes well, thank you!

Comment: @538ROMEO 33 in octal = 27 in decimal = 1B in hexadecimal

Answer (score 62):

You can write them like this :

```
 mode     : parseInt('0644',8)
```

In node and in modern browsers (see [compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-octal_and_binary_literals)), you can use octal literals:

```
 mode     : 0o644
```

Comment: I like this answer because it uses an integer type which makes it better for things like fs.chmod or fs.mkdir, which call for integers on the mode. Even if they "support" strings, it's a good idea to pass them the data type they expect.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `0o` prefix for octal numbers instead.

```
let x = 0o50;
console.log(x); //40
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Deprecated_octal

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this problem by using mode into string type.

**1st Method**

```
 let mode = "0766";
 fs.createWriteStream( fileName, {
        flags    : 'a',
        encoding : 'utf8',
        mode     : mode
    });
```

or

**2nd Method**

```
 fs.createWriteStream( fileName, {
        flags    : 'a',
        encoding : 'utf8',
        mode     : "0766"
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

I came across this problem too

```js
function getFirst(arr) {
    return arr[0]
}
let first = getFirst([10, 'hello', 96, 02])
console.log(first)
```

This is what I did to fix it

```js
function getFirst(arr) {
    return arr[0]
}
let first = getFirst([10, 'hello', 96, '02'])
console.log(first);
```

apparently it doesn't accept 0 as a start of number unless it's a string

Comment: This answer does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: @Tyler2P Maybe it doesn't, but it's the first thing that came up when I googled an error and this helped me solve it.