# How does eval work in JavaScript? Why does eval('011+011') not equal eval('11+11')

Tags: javascript

So my understanding is that eval() can take a string that is a mathematical expression and return the value of the expression. Why is it then that adding a '0' before a number e.g. changing '11' to '011' changes the result?

Comment: `eval` doesn't take a "string that is a mathematical expression", it takes a string that is *JavaScript source code*.

Comment: Type 011 on the JavaScript debug console

Comment: Using math.js, `math.eval()` will evaluate a math expression. https://mathjs.org/

Comment: On a side note, [you really shouldn't use `eval` unless you absolutely have to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18269797/what-does-eval-do-and-why-its-evil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `011` is an octal literal which is equal to decimal 9 (9 + 9 gives 18). Removing the `0` prefix makes the value decimal, so the result is decimal 11 (11 + 11 gives 22).

You can try it from a node REPL

```
> eval('011')
9
```

If you enable strict mode, it wont allow octal literals. [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34358331/why-are-octal-numeric-literals-not-allowed-in-strict-mode-and-what-is-the-worka)